# Data Visualization - Jupyter

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

```
data.option.value_counts()

1    599
2    622
3    279
4    453
Name: option, dtype: int64
```

I would like receive get results table and make a chart bar (for example bar plot) based on these results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First store the count in one variable

```
count = pd.value_counts(data['option'].values, sort=True)
```

Then plot it

```
count.plot.barh()
```

Comment: Thank You! How to change graph orientations and size?

Comment: you can use the figsize() and layout parameter, for more details refer here https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23.4/generated/pandas.DataFrame.plot.html

Comment: @emmak If this answered your question, please don't forget to click the check mark to accept it as the answer. Also see [what should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)